# PATH / opt / ml / input / data / validation does not exist! An error has occurred. Could you give me some advice on how to solve it?

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

When I performed the following AWS tutorial, I got an error when training the model.

https://aws.amazon.com/jp/getting-started/hands-on/build-train-deploy-machine-learning-model-sagemaker/

The error that occurred is "PATH /opt/ml/input/data/validation does not exist!"
As a result of investigation, there is only a metadata.json file in　"/opt/ml", and there isn't the input/data/validation folder.

I tried creating a "/opt/ml/input/data/validation" folder and copy the training.csv file, but I couldn't because I didn't have permission.

Could you give me some advice on how to solve it?

Comment: can you please post the whole stacktrace error ?

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
the whole stacktrace error is below;

Comment: xgb.fit({'train': TrainingInput})

2021-04-14 10:43:57 Starting - Starting the training job...

2021-04-14 10:44:21 Starting - Launching requested ML instancesProfilerReport-##########: InProgress

......
2021-04-14 10:45:26 Starting - Preparing the instances for training............
2021-04-14 10:47:21 Downloading - Downloading input data
2021-04-14 10:47:21 Training - Downloading the training image...
2021-04-14 10:47:58 Uploading - Uploading generated training modelArguments: train

Comment: [2021-04-14:10:47:48:INFO] Running standalone xgboost training.
[2021-04-14:10:47:48:INFO] Path /opt/ml/input/data/validation does not exist!

Comment: [2021-04-14:10:47:48:INFO] File size need to be processed in the node: 3.38mb. Available memory size in the node: 8407.13mb
[2021-04-14:10:47:48:INFO] Determined delimiter of CSV input is ','
[10:47:48] S3DistributionType set as FullyReplicated
[10:47:49] 28831x59 matrix with 1701029 entries loaded from /opt/ml/input/data/train?format=csv&label_column=0&delimiter=,
[10:47:49] src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 30 extra nodes, 14 pruned nodes, max_depth=5
[0]#011train-error:0.100482

Comment: [10:47:49] src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 30 extra nodes, 14 pruned nodes, max_depth=5

[1]#011train-error:0.099858
[10:47:49] src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 28 extra nodes, 22 pruned nodes, max_depth=5
[2]#011train-error:0.099754

Comment: I'm sorry it's too long to see.

Comment: But on the Jupyter Notebook,"opt/ml/input/data/validation/train.csv"　is exsisted.

Comment: please edit your post and properly format the stacktrace, it's unreadable in this form

Comment: Thank you for  your reply. I edit below;

Comment: xgb.fit({'train': TrainingInput})

Comment: 2021-04-14 10:43:57 Starting - Starting the training job...

Comment: 2021-04-14 10:44:21 Starting - Launching requested ML instancesProfilerReport-1618397037: InProgress
......

Comment: 2021-04-14 10:45:26 Starting - Preparing the instances for training............

Comment: 2021-04-14 10:47:21 Downloading - Downloading input data

Comment: 2021-04-14 10:47:21 Training - Downloading the training image...

Comment: 2021-04-14 10:47:58 Uploading - Uploading generated training modelArguments: train

Comment: [2021-04-14:10:47:48:INFO] Running standalone xgboost training.

Comment: [2021-04-14:10:47:48:INFO] Path /opt/ml/input/data/validation does not exist!

Comment: [2021-04-14:10:47:48:INFO] File size need to be processed in the node: 3.38mb. Available memory size in the node: 8407.13mb

Comment: [2021-04-14:10:47:48:INFO] Determined delimiter of CSV input is ','

Comment: [10:47:48] S3DistributionType set as FullyReplicated

Comment: [10:47:49] 28831x59 matrix with 1701029 entries loaded from /opt/ml/input/data/train?format=csv&label_column=0&delimiter=

Comment: [10:47:49] src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 30 extra nodes, 14 pruned nodes, max_depth=5
[0]#011train-error:0.100482

Comment: [10:47:49] src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 30 extra nodes, 14 pruned nodes, max_depth=5
[1]#011train-error:0.099858

Comment: [10:47:49] src/tree/updater_prune.cc:74: tree pruning end, 1 roots, 28 extra nodes, 22 pruned nodes, max_depth=5
[2]#011train-error:0.099754

Comment: That's all for the log. I can confirm that the training.csv file is stored in the folder under sagemaker.

Comment: ls /home/ec2-user/SageMaker

Comment: bank_clean.csv  lost+found/  train.csv  Untitled.ipynb